# c++ memory error: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind

I'm getting this error reported when I run my test program:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006d7320 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7ffff706ab96]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIdE10deallocateEPdm+0x20)[0x47715e]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEED2Ev+0x38)[0x474aea]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas6vectorIdNS1_15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEEEED2Ev+0x19)[0x473177]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas13vector_assignINS1_13scalar_assignENS1_6vectorIdNS1_15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEEEEENS1_11zero_vectorIdS6_EEEEvRT0_RKNS1_17vector_expressionIT1_EENS1_10sparse_tagE+0x2bf)[0x47b2d9]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas13vector_assignINS1_13scalar_assignENS1_6vectorIdNS1_15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEEEEENS1_11zero_vectorIdS6_EEEEvRT0_RKNS1_17vector_expressionIT1_EE+0x26)[0x4782f4]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas6vectorIdNS1_15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEEEE6assignINS1_11zero_vectorIdS4_EEEERS6_RKNS1_17vector_expressionIT_EE+0x23)[0x4771fd]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN5boost7numeric5ublas6vectorIdNS1_15unbounded_arrayIdSaIdEEEEaSINS1_11zero_vectorIdS4_EEEERS6_RKNS1_16vector_containerIT_EE+0x4e)[0x474b52]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN9DataPointC1Ev+0x101)[0x4682d7]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN16Manager13processSampleEP6Sample+0x40)[0x46a49e]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN16Manager7addDataEP6Samplei+0x108)[0x46a8b6]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN16Manager14SetLogFileDataEP6Samplei+0x90)[0x46904a]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN36MyprogTest_testGetValuesToFilter_Test8TestBodyEv+0x6b)[0x4706a5]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8internal38HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupportedINS_4TestEvEET0_PT_MS4_FS3_vEPKc+0x52)[0x49eb29]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8internal35HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupportedINS_4TestEvEET0_PT_MS4_FS3_vEPKc+0x45)[0x499b76]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing4Test3RunEv+0xb9)[0x487461]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8TestInfo3RunEv+0xf6)[0x487bb8]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8TestCase3RunEv+0xe1)[0x48815f]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8internal12UnitTestImpl11RunAllTestsEv+0x272)[0x48ce3e]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8internal38HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupportedINS0_12UnitTestImplEbEET0_PT_MS4_FS3_vEPKc+0x52)[0x49ffcb]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8internal35HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupportedINS0_12UnitTestImplEbEET0_PT_MS4_FS3_vEPKc+0x45)[0x49aa62]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(_ZN7testing8UnitTest3RunEv+0x5e)[0x48bbee]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test(main+0x3e)[0x4a8b76]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff700d76d]
/home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test[0x466399]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-004d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11152935                           /home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test
006d1000-006d2000 r--p 000d1000 08:01 11152935                           /home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test
006d2000-006d3000 rw-p 000d2000 08:01 11152935                           /home/me/work/co/myprog/build/myprog_test
006d3000-006f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff6fec000-7ffff71a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12452670                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff71a1000-7ffff73a0000 ---p 001b5000 08:01 12452670                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff73a0000-7ffff73a4000 r--p 001b4000 08:01 12452670                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff73a4000-7ffff73a6000 rw-p 001b8000 08:01 12452670                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff73a6000-7ffff73ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff73ab000-7ffff73c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12455438                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff73c0000-7ffff75bf000 ---p 00015000 08:01 12455438                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff75bf000-7ffff75c0000 r--p 00014000 08:01 12455438                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff75c0000-7ffff75c1000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 12455438                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff75c1000-7ffff76bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12452678                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff76bc000-7ffff78bb000 ---p 000fb000 08:01 12452678                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff78bb000-7ffff78bc000 r--p 000fa000 08:01 12452678                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff78bc000-7ffff78bd000 rw-p 000fb000 08:01 12452678                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff78bd000-7ffff799f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 794196                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff799f000-7ffff7b9e000 ---p 000e2000 08:01 794196                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7b9e000-7ffff7ba6000 r--p 000e1000 08:01 794196                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7ba6000-7ffff7ba8000 rw-p 000e9000 08:01 794196                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7ba8000-7ffff7bbd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7bbd000-7ffff7bd5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12452672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff7bd5000-7ffff7dd4000 ---p 00018000 08:01 12452672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff7dd4000-7ffff7dd5000 r--p 00017000 08:01 12452672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7dd6000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 12452672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff7dd6000-7ffff7dda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12452684                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7fd6000-7ffff7fdb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ff7000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:01 12452684                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 12452684                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I've run it through gdb, and the line that's causing it is indirectly this constructor call, when it gets to the line in the constructor

```
DataPointPtr data(new DataPoint());
=>
gyro_stdev = zero_vector;
```

With these definitions for DataPoint and Ptr:

```
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> vector;

struct DataPoint {
  DataPoint(void);
  long timestamp;
  bool derived;

  vector accel;
  vector accel_filtered;

  vector gyro_filtered;
  vector gyro_stdev;

  vector gyro;

  vector velocity;
  vector position;
  vector orientation;

  vector gravity;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<DataPoint> DataPointPtr;

boost::numeric::ublas::zero_vector<double> zero_vector(3);

DataPoint::DataPoint(void) {
  derived = false;

  accel = zero_vector;
  accel_filtered = zero_vector;

  gyro_filtered = zero_vector;
  gyro_stdev = zero_vector;

  gyro = zero_vector;

  position = zero_vector;
  velocity = zero_vector;
  orientation = zero_vector;
  gravity = zero_vector;

}
```

I've also run this same program through valgrind and I get an incredible amount of output, most of which looks something like this, varying only depending on which trigonometric function I'm using (sin, tan, atan2 etc.)

```
==4161== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4161==    at 0x536CC9D: __sin_sse2 (s_sin.c:115)
==4161==    by 0x46B23C: AccelGyroManager::getGyroEstimate(long, boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > >, boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > >) (AccelGyroManager.cxx:659)
==4161==    by 0x46BD53: AccelGyroManager::deriveData(int) (AccelGyroManager.cxx:753)
==4161==    by 0x46957A: AccelGyroManager::GetEstimate(long, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*) (AccelGyroManager.cxx:294)
==4161==    by 0x467150: AgmanDllTest_testDeriveInterpolatedData_Test::TestBody() (agman_test.cxx:144)
==4161==    by 0x49EB28: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2090)
==4161==    by 0x499B75: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2126)
==4161==    by 0x487460: testing::Test::Run() (gtest.cc:2162)
==4161==    by 0x487BB7: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest.cc:2338)
==4161==    by 0x48815E: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest.cc:2445)
==4161==    by 0x48CE3D: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest.cc:4237)
==4161==    by 0x49FFCA: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2090)
==4161==
```

This problem is a bit confusing to me.  Is it possible that I'm running out of memory?  This exact same constructor call succeeds about 400 times before this point in the program.

And valgrind's reference to s_sin.c is also confusing, I can't find this file anywhere..

Any advice or suggestions on what to look at or poke around with are much appreciated.

Comment: You're seeing the victim code that notices the problem, not the perpetrator that causes it. You need to look over the valgrind output. The excerpt you posted is a trivial issue -- a jump or move that depends on an uninitialized value and not related to the problem you're trying to solve. (`s_sin.c` is part of the math library that contains an SSE2 implementation of a sine function.)

Comment: As @DavidSchwartz says, you are seeing the victim, not the perpetrator. That one is either some pointer that isn't initialized, or initialized wrongly (some forced cast?), perhaps initialized with the address of a local variable? Perhaps some array overrun stepping on a pointer (look for pointers defined before arrays or C strings)? Mixing up `new[]` and `new`? `new` and `malloc`?

Comment: I'd say it's almost certainly an "array overrun" that causes the problem in the first report. 

The Valgrind output is saying that you are using variables that haven't been initialized. You will need to track back to where the variables in, for example, getGyroEstimate is coming from, when you call `sin()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found my problem.  As Mats Petersson suggested, my problem was in fact an array overrun.  It turns out that I had this little gem buried in my utilities for my unit tests:

```
SampleArray createPredictableSamples(int count) {
  SampleArray samples(new Sample[100]);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  ... do stuff
  }
  return samples;
}
```

*(notice the static array creation of size 100, when the method is parameterized...)*

### So just remember, **test code has bugs too!!**

Here's the method I used to discover this.

When I posted my question, I had made a bunch of changes since the last time I ran the tests.  The output from running

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./test
```

was a little overwhelming because of this.  So I backed out of most of those changes (using my version control to keep them available), and then re applied them one by one as functional sets.

Each time I introduced one change set, I re-ran the tests, and used valgrind to check for memory errors.  Finally, I made one change (changing my test array size) that produced a huge amount of output.  I searched through that (as valgrind suggests) for "writes" to uninitialized memory (i.e. for buffer overruns).  And lo and behold, it lead me right to the problem, line-numbers and all.

Along the way, I also found a couple of other memory leaks in my test code.  Now, I still have more work to do cleaning up test code for memory leaks, but I at least have gotten rid of the buffer overrun.

Thanks Mats, David, and vonbrand for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you ran valgrind already!  Now I think we should address its concerns.

If `getGyroEstimate()` is reading a hardware device, it may be that valgrind sees the value as uninitialized even if things are being done correctly.  If you think this is the case (and maybe even temporarily if not), you can add it to the valgrind "suppressions" file (valgrind can help you do this semi-automatically if you use the `--gen-suppressions` option).  Then you won't be distracted by this possibly innocuous warning, and can move on to fixing other things it will probably complain about (some of which are probably the root cause of your crash).

Comment: +1 for the mention of suppressions in valgrind!  I hadn't heard of that before...